# "for" or "while" loop for dynamic OLED scrolling?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, scroll

I have code (below bottom)  that will scroll a long string across my OLED...it works, but it's ugly and not dynamic.
I am thinking that I can get the number of characters in `var_read_file` and then either do a `for` loop or `while` loop to cause the string to scroll based on the length of the string.

I am thinking something like this code:

```
my_str_count = (len(var_read_file))
loopcounter = 0
scrollindex = 1
while my_str_count > loopcounter:
    scrollindex = scrollindex + 5
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, scrollindex, 15, 1)
    display.show()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    loopcounter = loopcounter + 1
```

Here is the current ugly code :

```
def myoutboundscroll():
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, 0, 15, 1)
    display.show()
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, -5, 15, 1)
    display.show()
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, -10, 15, 1)
    display.show()
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, -15, 15, 1)
    display.show()
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, -20, 15, 1)
    display.show()
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, -25, 15, 1)
    display.show()
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, -30, 15, 1)
    display.show()
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, -35, 15, 1)
    display.show()
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, -40, 15, 1)
    display.show()
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, -45, 15, 1)
    display.show()
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, -50, 15, 1)
    display.show()
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, -55, 15, 1)
    display.show()
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, -60, 15, 1)
    display.show()
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, -65, 15, 1)
    display.show()
    display.fill(0)
    display.text(var_read_file, -70, 15, 1)
    display.show()
```

Comment: I should have prefaced with "I'm a beginner" and wasn't sure how to do it more efficiently.

Comment: What type is `display`? How is it defined?

Comment: ssd1306 OLED display

Comment: You didn't understand. You're using a variable named `display`. That variable is an instance of a class, with `show`, `fill`, `text` methods, but we don't know which class it is, nor have the documentation on how to use it. If your displaying something on a screen, you're probably using a toolkit like Qt or GTK, and then shouldn't try to handle animations by hand (know it, been there).

Comment: With your screen reference, I found https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_SSD1306 . Is that the library you're using? If you're doing embedded programming, that's a different beast.

Comment: yes that is one but I think its an older one,  I think its now included in an adafruit circuit python library...but I figured out the answer and posted it here, while it does use a global variable I am re-writing the code to make that routine local instead of a function.

Answer (score 0):

With some minor tweaking my idea worked:

```
def myoutboundscroll():
    global my_str_out_count
    loopcounter = 0
    scrollindex = 0
    while my_str_out_count > loopcounter:
        scrollindex = scrollindex - 5
        display.fill(0)
        display.text(var_read_file, scrollindex, 15, 1)
        display.show()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        loopcounter = loopcounter + 1
```

Comment: You should avoid globals. Please give us a complete example we can run, not soething out of the blue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer:

```
def myoutboundscroll(text, duration_in_sec):
    shift = -5  # text position increment
    text_len = len(text)
    time_incr = duration_in_sec / text_len
    for scrollindex in range(0, text_len * shift, shift):
        display.fill(0)
        display.text(text, scrollindex, 15, 1)
        display.show()
        time.sleep(time_incr)
```